# How do I add additional query arguments through the Views API?

Tags: views

I've implemented hook_views_query_alter($view, $query) where I'm replacing a field with a subquery (which returns a single COUNT value). However, even though it works very well to replace the field with a subquery, I'm having trouble adding one
or more arguments to that subquery. Say I've got this query :

```
SELECT tid, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {download} AS d WHERE d.tid = t.tid AND d.updated > :timestamp) AS downloads FROM {track} AS t
```

I'd like to get a track and the number of downloads for that track after a certain point in time. I would thus need to set the ':timestamp' argument for the query. However, I can't figure out how to do that for Views.

Does anyone have experience with this? Either how to provide a subquery as a field (and not condition as in "WHERE) or how to just set an extra argument directly on the $query object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a subquery in a WHERE condition, using hook\_views\_query\_alter()](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124621/add-a-subquery-in-a-where-condition-using-hook-views-query-alter)