# Add a subquery in a WHERE condition, using hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: views

I tried to add a subquery like this:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view) {
  $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
    'field' => 'node.nid',
    'value' => 'SELECT SUBSTRING(source, 6) FROM {url_alias} WHERE alias LIKE "pros/%"',
    'operator' => 'in',
  );
}
```

I have a specific case where nodes are created with aliases starting with `pros/` or not, and I want to get only them.

In a simple raw SQL query, I'd go with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM node node
WHERE node.nid IN (SELECT SUBSTRING(source, 6)
                   FROM {url_alias}
                   WHERE alias LIKE "pros/%")
```

But I can't find out how to do this using `hook_views_query_alter()`.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but a simpler (& more scalable) alternative might be to use taxonomy.

Comment: @Andy this is part of a bigger project, where it's not possible to switch to taxonomy anymore. That said, it wasn't used for other reasons. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally I think its right to use [views_join_subquery](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/class/views_join_subquery/7). But the subquery you are using is with `IN` keyword is always slow and will produce same result as using a `LEFT JOIN` joining with `node.nid` field.

You can try creating a [views_join](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/class/views_join/7) and adding the `url_alias` table by add_field method while the node table will be the left table.

I don't have the code at the moment but you can have a look at the below links. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851945/add-table-join-where-and-order-by-to-views-query-in-views-query-alter

http://www.wordpressecoder.com/2014/01/how-to-alter-views-query-with-multiple.html 
http://www.yellowpencil.com/blog/last-ditch-fix-programmatically-changing-drupal-7-view

Comment: I don't see how joins will help me in this case. Care to elaborate? I've already seen these links, but joins are not what I care about here.

Comment: Then I think views_join_subquery is the way to do it. I don't have any working examples at the moment. I'd love to try that one out and I'll post if I make any.

Comment: views_join_subquery does a join. So, no, it doesn't help.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I think the suggestion here is to try `SELECT * FROM node JOIN url_alias ON nid = SUBSTR(source, 6) WHERE alias LIKE 'pros/%'`

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I went through `hook_views_pre_execute()` and using a `LEFT JOIN`..

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute($view) {
  $query = $view->build_info['query'];
  $query->leftJoin('url_alias', 'u', 'node.nid = substr(u.source, 6)');
  $query->where("u.alias LIKE 'pros/%'");
}
```

Something that tripped me up was that I had to use simple quotes around the `LIKE`, it didn't work with double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great example of how to do subqueries in the Taxonomy Views integration. You can see it in [views_handler_argument_term_node_tid_depth::query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!taxonomy!views_handler_argument_term_node_tid_depth.inc/function/views_handler_argument_term_node_tid_depth%3A%3Aquery/7.x-3.x).

Ultimately though, the trick is that you build an entire sub-query using `db_select()`, and then just add that entire resulting object into the Views query object using the add_where() method.

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view) {
  $sub_query = db_select('foo', 'f')
    ->fields('f', array('nid'))
    ->condition('f.bar', 'baz');
  $view->query->add_where(0, 'node.nid', $subquery, 'IN');
}
```

This ability to use a select subquery is documented in the [Views add_where() documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where/7.x-3.x) (but unfortunately due to the rendering on api.drupal.org, it doesn't show the example).

You could also probably manually add the where to the `$view->query->where[1]['conditions']` array, but using the method instead of manipulating the array directly is recommended.

Comment: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::add_where()